# Power rule for modulus and complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

If $z \in \mathbb{C}$ then is
\begin{equation}
|z|^{1/2} = |z^{1/2}|
\end{equation}
true? Note: $| z |$ denotes the modulus of $z$.

I know this is true if $z$ is real and I have tried some examples in the complex case and they seem to work but is there a proof for any $z$? Also, what about
\begin{equation}
|z|^n = |z^n|? 
\end{equation}

Is there only certain values of $n$ or $z$ that satisfy this?

Comment: The square root function is not well-defined on the complex numbers so you'll need to address that first.

Comment: Although this is essentially orthogonal to your question (it concerns the *argument* rather than the *modulus* of a powers), one application of [De Moivre's formula](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Failure_for_non-integer_powers,_and_generalization) is to show how to calculate $n$th roots (or more generally, rational powers of a complex number) in polar form.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments

Answer (score 0):

By exponential form $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$ with $\rho\ge 0$ we have

- $|z|=\rho \implies |z|^\frac12 =\rho^\frac12$
- $z^\frac12 =\rho^\frac12e^{ik\frac \theta 2},\;k=0,1 \implies |z^\frac12|=\rho^\frac12|e^{ik\frac \theta 2}|=\rho^\frac12$

in a similar way we can prove the case $|z|^n=|z^n|$.